# I want to detect messages sent by a specific user. (discrd.py on message)

Tags: discord.py

I want to check the number of messages sent by a specific user when sec is 0. If the number of messages sent by the user is 0, it tries to delete the channel.

```
        while (sec != 0 ):
            sec = sec-1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(sec)
            if sec == 30:
                await a.send(f'{message.author.mention}')
            if sec == 0:
                await a.delete()
                await message.author.send('f')
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the number of messages sent by a user you would utilize the channel history like this:

```py
msgcount = 0
channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel_id) 
messages = await channel.history(limit = None).flatten()
for message in messages:
   if user == message.author:
      msgcount += 1
```

This will count all messages by that user, in the designated channel and store in msgcount. You can replace the limit of None with any number of max messages you would like to loop through. Depending on the total messages in the channel, for instance if it has over 10,000 this can take a while to loop through.

If you do not need the history, and would like to do for only new messages after a starting point it would be better to use: `async def on_message(message):` to keep track of the messages and you can set an if statement to only monitor certain channels or certain users. After whatever trigger you're using to start checking before X time, you can use a similar if statement and counter.

Comment: there is nothing as `ctx.guild.channel` to use get_channel u have to use `client` or if u want to get channel in command then use `ctx.channel`

Comment: @DjWalkzz If you're using rewrite you can use ```ctx.guild.get_channel(#Channel_ID_HERE#)``` if you have the channel ID. Otherwise first need to discord.utils.get to retrieve. As to using client or not, that is dependent on if he is using cogs or not. I have a COG that is utilizing that right now and doing something similar as what OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: i dont think the OP is using rewrite ,lets see which code helps him

Answer (score 0):

u need to have id of the user and check check it like this :

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(id)
messages = await channel.history(limit=None).flatten()
for msg in messages:
    if msg.author.id == id of that user:
        return
await channel.delete()
```

so it will fetch the messages and then will check if user have messaged or not if yes it will stop there and will do nothing if not then it will delete channel.